# Using multiple .dir-locals.el

Tags: directory-local-variables

Say I have two directories `A` and `B`, with `A` containing `B`. Both `A` and `B` have directory local variables specified through their own `.dir-locals.el` files. `B/.dir-locals.el` whenever emacs visits a file in `B`. However, I want emacs to load `B/.dir-locals.el` and `A/.dir-locals.el`. Is there a way to customize this behaviour? If not, how do I achieve this behaviour?